# Printing simultaneously from 2 lists

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop

Assume the following 2 lists:

```
l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
l2 = ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
```

I am looking for the following output

```
a f
b g
c h
d i
e
```

Here is what I have tried

```
for x, y in l1, l2:
    print(x, y)
```

but this has too many items to unpack, does anybody know how I could get the output I need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use python [zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
from itertools import zip_longest

l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
l2 = ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i']

print (zip_longest (l1, l2, fillvalue = ''))
```